# Which is the best way to send data to server?

Tags: javascript, json, post

I'm using a POST request to send data to the server, but I would like if it's better to send a classic request like this:

```
$.post(
    "<?php echo Settings\Path\URL::$ajax?>/ajaxValidator.php",
    {
                      item : "Captcha",
        recaptchaChallenge : Recaptcha.get_challenge(),
         recaptchaResponse : Recaptcha.get_response()
    },
    function(result){
        if(result == "true"){
            signup();
        } else {
            $("#signupRecaptchaError").show();
            recaptchaCreate();
        }
    }
);
```

or if it's better to send data using a POST request using JSON like this:

```
var data = {
                      item : "Captcha",
        recaptchaChallenge : Recaptcha.get_challenge(),
         recaptchaResponse : Recaptcha.get_response()
}

$.post(
    "<?php echo Settings\Path\URL::$ajax?>/ajaxValidator.php",
    data,
    function(result){
        if(result == "true"){
            signup();
        } else {
            $("#signupRecaptchaError").show();
            recaptchaCreate();
        }
    }
);
```

If there's any difference can you tell what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. You've only changed how the client gathers it's data. The request is exactly the same.

Which method of gathering data is better is dependent on the overall structure of your framework.

Looking at your code I can identify some other issues that need addressing before you can start worrying about large architectural questions like this. So my recommendation is: it doesn't matter for now, until you can come up with with a clear reason why one is better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any difference but I personally prefer the latter. Having your parameters abstracted gives you more flexibility. It allows you to swap the value during runtime if needed.